# Sending list of dicts as value of dict with requests.post going wrong

Tags: python, django, post, python-requests, oauth-2.0

I have clien-server app.
I localized trouble and there logic of this:

Client:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests


def fixing:
    response = requests.post('http://url_for_auth/', data={'client_id': 'client_id', 
                             'client_secret':'its_secret', 'grant_type': 'password', 
                             'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'})
    f = response.json()
    data = {'coordinate_x': 12.3, 'coordinate_y': 8.4, 'address': u'\u041c, 12', 
            'products': [{'count': 1, 'id': 's123'},{'count': 2, 'id': 's124'}]}
    data.update(f)
    response = requests.post('http://url_for_working/, data=data)
    response.text #There I have an Error about which I will say later
```

oAuth2 working well. But in server-side I have no products in request.data

```
<QueryDict: {u'token_type': [u'type_is_ok'], u'access_token': [u'token_is_ok'], 
             u'expires_in': [u'36000'], u'coordinate_y': [u'8.4'], 
             u'coordinate_x': [u'12.3'], u'products': [u'count', u'id', u'count', 
             u'id'], u'address': [u'\u041c, 12'], u'scope': [u'read write'], 
             u'refresh_token': [u'token_is_ok']}>
```

This part of QueryDict make me sad...

```
'products': [u'count', u'id', u'count', u'id']
```

And when I tried to make python dict:

```
request.data.dict()
... u'products': u'id', ...
```

And for sure other fields working well with Django serializer's validation. But not that, because there I have wrong values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like request (because it have x-www-encoded-form default) cant include list of dicts as value for key in dict so... I should use json in this case.
Finally I maked this func:

```
import requests
import json


def fixing:
    response = requests.post('http://url_for_auth/', data={'client_id': 'client_id', 
                         'client_secret':'its_secret', 'grant_type': 'password', 
                         'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'})
    f = response.json()
    headers = {'authorization': f['token_type'].encode('utf-8')+' '+f['access_token'].encode('utf-8'), 
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    data = {'coordinate_x': 12.3, 'coordinate_y': 8.4, 'address': u'\u041c, 12', 
        'products': [{'count': 1, 'id': 's123'},{'count': 2, 'id': 's124'}]}
    response = requests.post('http://url_for_working/', data=json.dumps(data), 
                              headers=headers)
    response.text
```

There I got right response.
Solved!

Comment: This solution will not work, at a quick glance 'http://url_for_working/ is missing a closing single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i would like to refresh this topic, cause i have similar problem to this and above solution doesn`t work for me.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import pprint
import json
from requests import auth
from requests.models import HTTPBasicAuth


payload = {
    'description': 'zxcy',
    'tags':[{
            'id': 22,
            'label': 'Card'}]
}


files = {'file': open('JAM5.pdf','rb')}
client_id = 32590
response = requests.post('https://system...+str(client_id)'  , files=files ,data=payload,  auth=HTTPBasicAuth(...)
```

Above code succesfully add file to CRM system and description to added file, but i have to add label to this too, and it`s seems doesn`t work at all

When i try it with data=json.dumps(payload) i got this:

```
    raise ValueError("Data must not be a string.")
ValueError: Data must not be a string.
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31273442)